# Adjusting bounce rate in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to chance the way a bounce is registered in Google Analytics.

This is my analytics code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1x', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I want to make it so that a bounce only registers if they left the site before 5 seconds elapsed. How could I go about doing this? I know there should be some way to do it with `js`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send a [Custom Event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation), so as to "ping" Google Analytics and prevent a Bounce from being logged.

This could be something like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
         if (typeof window.ga !== 'undefined') {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Bounce Disabling', 'Ping', '5 second timeout');
         }
      }, 5*1000); // 5000ms delay
   })();
</script>
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to record data based on the time elapsed on the page, you could use something like the following.

Passing the `elapsedTime` value as the last parameter of the `ga()` call will allow you to have Metrics like *Average Event Value* automatically computed -- should that be of any use to you.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var initTime = new Date().getTime();

        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
            var closeTime = new Date().getTime();
            var elapsedTime = closeTime - initTime; // Time elapsed since page loaded (in ms).

            if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
                if (elapsedTime <= 60 * 1000) { // 60 000 ms = 1 min
                    // Page loaded less than 1 minute ago:
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Page View Time', 'Duration', 'Under 1 minute', elapsedTime);
                } else {
                    // Page loaded over 1 minute ago:
                    ga('send', 'event', 'Page View Time', 'Duration', 'Over 1 minute', elapsedTime);
                }
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you have any information on how I can modify time spent on site? Anything under 1 minute to count as 1 minute and anything about 1 minute to count as 10? Need to do this to differentiate some things.

Comment: You won't be able to change the Time spent on site/page Metric used in Reports, as it is computed on Google's side. You could go to Audience > Behavior > Engagement and check the time buckets available, and/or export the data in Excel and add it up there, if that ever fits your needs. Can you provide more information on your specific needs?

Comment: Thanks. I've heard it may be possible if I use old analytics code? Just need a bit of a framework to modify the way time spent on site is reported. (I've Facebook messaged you, my name is Martin K)'

Comment: Using the Classic Analytics API, you could use [_setSessionTimeout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSessionTimeout) to set the maximum duration for a Session, but that is basically the same as what you can do on the Admin section of Analytics... Otherwise, you could fire Custom Events at `window.unload()`, with different values depending on time spend on the page (one Event when under a minute, another when over a minute), and compare the count for both.

Comment: Thank you :) Would the latter solution show up in analytics?

Comment: I updated my answer to add a code sample of how you could track how many people viewed your page for under/over one minute.

Comment: AWESOME! Can I be running the new version of GA or do I need to change to classic?

Comment: That will work with the new version of GA (Universal). Although this will only log Custom Events into 2 "buckets", you could then create some custom Dashboards with nice Pie Charts or Bar Graphs straight into Analytics to display that information.